# UIImagePickerController and UINavigationControllerDelegate implementation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to pick an image from gallery using `UIImagePickerController`.

If my view controller is not mentioning `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. I will be getting following error while trying to set `UIImagePickerController` delegate.

[image]

But just mentioning `UINavigationControllerDelegate` will resolve the compile time error. Without even implementing any extra functions.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate 
,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

If someone could explain me the rational behind the same, it would be really appreciable.

I am using

```
Swift 4.2

Xcode 10.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: screenshot of UIImagePickerController declaration]
From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) you can see that UIImagePickerController inherits from UINavigationController.

[image: screenshot of delegate declaration]
Looking at delegate declaration it is clear that it requires you to confirm to both `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` & `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

**Why does delegate requires you to confirm to both protocols?**

`UIImagePickerController` is a system interface. This class is intended to be used as-is and allows no visual modifications. As you can see from a screenshot below it comes with a navigation bar.

Some of the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods like `imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_:)` requires to communicate with `UINavigationController` in order to receive events.

This is why `UIImagePickerController` must verify that you are confirming to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Hence you are seeing the error. Also note that `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods are optional so that you don't actually need to implement them and this is why it simply removes error when you mention `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

[image: screenshot of UIIMagePickerController]

Comment: Thanks for the proper explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerController's delegate is defined as

```
@property(nullable,nonatomic,weak) id <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

So the delegate you want to set must conform UINavigationControllerDelegate.

UINavigationControllerDelegate has no mandatory fields. So you do not need to implement any function or variable to conform that. Hence your error is solved.

[image: Screenshot of UINavDelegate]

Answer (score 0):

The rational is very simple if you need to monitor when the vc ( imagePicker ) is shown then implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate`  methods so it will has a meaning otherwise it's useless , but it's mandatory